# is there anyway to directly email videos or upload a video from iphoto to youtube?

Tags: video, photos.app, file-sharing, youtube

When i download images and video from my iphone everything shows up under pictures in my iphoto library.  When i open iphoto i can scroll through pictures and videos but when i click on a video, i can play it but i can't see:

1. how to upload to youtube (surprised this is not listed in the share section)
2. how to email directly from iphoto (get a messagebox saying "Can't email videos"

can someone please advise on the best way to do the 2 things above as i thought they would be supported out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself. But I know if you have a video open in QuickTime the Youtube option is available there.

So basically you can 1)select "Reveal in Finder" from the File menu, 2) open the video in QuickTime and then 3)share to Youtube. Good luck.